# issue with my multiplication game on adobe flash AS6

Tags: flash, if-statement, math, timer, actionscript

I am a novice at Adobe Flash and I am having a problem with my maths game I am creating, firstly the timer doesn't work as it doesn't even show up when I run the program, and secondly my if statement doesn't work, I am trying to do it as when I answer the question correctly I gain 10 points and it generated a random question, right now the points system only goes up when when the sum of the values = 0 regardless of what I input.

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        var Num1:int ;
        var Num2:int ;
        var Answer:int ;
        var Score:int=0;
        var UserInput:String;
        var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,60);

        public function Main() {
            // constructor code
            gotoAndStop(1);
            Start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, StartFunct);
        }

        function StartFunct(e:Event) {
            gotoAndStop(2);
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickhandler);

            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickhandler2);
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,checkFunction);
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,Endgame);
        }

        function checkFunction(event:MouseEvent):void {
            Answer= Num1*Num2;
            if(int(TotalBox) == Answer) {
                Score=Score+10
            }
            else Score=Score
        }

        function clickhandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            Num1  = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
            Num2  = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

            num1Box.text = String(Num1);
            num2Box.text = String(Num2);
            UserInput = "";
        }

        function clickhandler2(event:MouseEvent):void {
            Score = Score;
            ScoreBox.text = String(Score);
        }

        function Endgame(event:TimerEvent):void {
            if (myTimer.currentCount==0) 
                gotoAndPlay(3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're evaluating **TotalBox**, but where is it?

Comment: Use `myTimer.start();` when you you need it to activate. Is `Totalbox` a textField? Does `if(int(TotalBox.text) == Answer)` work for you? You can increment with just `Score += 10;` (adds +10 to current Score) and if you are not changing Score, there is no need for `Score = Score`, since only the conditions of `IF` statement would cause a change.